# Fetching google search results (more than 10) using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-search, google-search-api, web-search

I have to fetch the google search results available after the first page of google response using javascript.
My use case is to fetch all the urls available on multiple google search results. Currently using xpath **scraper** I am able to achieve it for the first 10 results. But for other pages I am not able to get the content.

I have tried Google Custom search but it requires API key and CX which I am not allowed to create and moreover the API has a limitation of returning only 10 results at a time.

Please suggest a way forward as I am struck and not finding a way ahead.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any leads on this?